# issue with promise Node.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time and it's too confusing so i thought i'd ask.

```js
var listenKey = "";

const createListenKey = async () => {
  await axios({
    url: "/api/v3/userDataStream",
    method: "POST",
    baseURL: "https://api.binance.com",
    headers: {
      "X-MBX-APIKEY":
        "H48w9CLuTtTi955qWjcjjEKhh0Ogb3jnnluYucXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    var key = response.data.listenKey;
    console.log(key, "created");
    return key;
  });
};

listenKey = createListenKey();

listenKey.then((key) => {
  console.log(key);
});
```

the console.log in the last but one line is printing undefined. Why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you don't return anything from `createListenKey`. You shouldn't mix explicit promises and async-await.

Comment: You don't return anything from createListenKey function. Calling await is not the same as returning promises.

Comment: @Lennholm is right +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not return anything from the async function `createListenKey`

```
const asynF = async ()=>{


Promise.resolve(1).then(res=>{

 //Simulating response from axios call
 console.log(res)
})

// you are not returning anyting from this function  equivalent of => return ;
}

asynF().then(res=>{
//this would log undefined 
console.log(res)
})
```

As you know async function returns a promise you have two options make the outer wrapper a async function as well and just use await like below

```
const key = await createListenKey(config)
```

or else

you could simply do this

```
   return createListenKey(config).then(res=>{

 listenKey = res
})
```

can't say much more without knowing context.
Might I suggest not to mix then and async wait together

Answer (score 1):

Because the `createListenKey()` function doesn't return anything. The return statement in the then clause inside that function is scoped in the then block. To return a value from an async function, you need to do something like this.

```js
const createListenKey = async () => {
  const response = await axios({
    url: "/api/v3/userDataStream",
    method: "POST",
    baseURL: "https://api.binance.com",
    headers: {
      "X-MBX-APIKEY":
        "H48w9CLuTtTi955qWjcjjEKhh0Ogb3jnnluYucXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    },
  })

  var key = response.data.listenKey;
  console.log(key, "created");
  return key;
};
```

Comment: When i try to assign the return to a variable outside the function, its running before the data is fetched from the API. How do i come around this without using an IIFE async function?

Comment: So can you elaborate on this a bit what is the context.

Comment: So based on this answer, to assign the return to a variable out side the scope of the function ill have to use IIFE async like this 


(async () => {
  listenKey = await createListenKey();

})();

if i don't it shows Promise<pending>

is there any way other than using IIFE async?

Comment: @KautilyaKondragunta If you use async functions in the global scope, you need to wrap it in IIFE. Node.js 14 supports top-level await but it's not LTS yet.